# IF current url equals Onepage Checkout hide element ELSE show element - Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework2, magento-1.7

I am trying to write a simple script to hide the "checkout" button located on the sidebar mini cart in Magento if on the checkout page. For obvious reasons I don't think the checkout button should still be visible if the customer is already on the checkout page...

Here is what I have done but Its not working and I am not sure how far off I am.

```
   <?php if(Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage') == Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Checking out...') ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="btn btn-mini btn-success" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
  <?php endif ?>
```

If someone could be kind enough to give me a shift in the right direction I'd be grateful OR even let me know of a better method...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage') // or $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage')
```

This will get the url for the checkout/onepage route

```
Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()
```

this will get you the current url

Now compare them:

```
<?php if(Mage::getURL('checkout/onepage') == Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()) ?>
```

Comment: Perfect.. I've added the amended code to show exactly how it works just in case somebody else need to do something similar